# Is there a Terminal command to know the macOS installed but from an external hard drive or from macOS recovery?

Tags: terminal

How can I know the macOS version (such as 10.12.1) installed on the startup drive if I don't have the password (or has filevault encryption and I don't have the password).  I wonder if there's a way to know it by using a Terminal command from macOS recovery or by starting from an External storage disk.

Comment: Full disk encryption being enabled and you not knowing the password is quite a game changer for your question, and it’s easy to overlook when it’s not explicitly in the title. To get more helpful answers, you may want to include that fact in the title of your post.

Answer (score 7):

The ProductVersion is stored within the SystemVersion.plist file in CoreServices. This can be read using defaults:

```
defaults read /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion ProductVersion
```

When you're accessing the startup disk from another volume, you'll need to provide the full path to both defaults and /System:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/defaults read /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/usr/bin/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion ProductVersion
```

Comment: You can get a little more info (mostly the build number) by leaving off "ProductVersion".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sw_vers`

**Internal Drive:**

```
➜  ~ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.4
BuildVersion:   17***
```

**External Drive:**

You can simply consult the files that `sw_vers` use

```
➜  ~ man sw_vers

[...]

FILES
     /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
     /System/Library/CoreServices/ServerVersion.plist
```

So in order to access to theses files on your external volume, you can simply do:

```
✗ cat /Volumes/YOUR_VOLUME_NAME/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass in a separate volume into sw_vers, otherwise this'll read the host rather than the external hard drive volume?

Comment: Oh you're right, I've edited my answer

Comment: sorry mate, what do I type in Terminal then?  Startup volume is Macintosh HD and it's a typical default install on a macbook pro..

Comment: @Antonio23249 I've edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can also simply have a look at the file `/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` (which is the same as what the `default` command in the other answers does)... it's simple plist file in XML.